# Symfony2 the good .htaccess for the prod

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I use this .htaccess for my symfony2 project :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But with this .htaccess I've duplicate content: `http://domain/page == http://domain/web/page`

I can access to my website with / and /web/ . How to redirect all /web/* to /* ?

When I put `DocumentRoot /data/sites/web/medesthebe/www/web` before `RewriteEngine On` that's give me an error 500.

*PS : It's a basic hosting not a VPS or dedicated server. I've not access to vhosts*
Thx

Comment: Move DocumentRoot to the `/web` and use the supplied `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Just set DocumentRoot in your htaccess;

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/symfony_project/web
```

Comment: I put this line before _RewriteEngine On_ : `DocumentRoot /data/sites/web/medesthebe/www/` and i get an error 500. I'm sure about the directory i checked with realpath()

Comment: @Hotgeart- DocumentRoot /data/sites/web/medesthebe/www/ is symfony2 project location? or it is ```web``` folder in symfony2 project folder?

Answer (score 0):

You usually can change the root path of the domain in the hosting management panel. Instead of setting it directly to the whatever www folder, use the web subfolder.

It worked for me instead of creating complex rules in the DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess to redirect everything to /web.